# SpreadsheetGear SetArray of double when double.NaN is present

Tags: excel, nan, spreadsheetgear

I have a simplified test scenario created where I have a spreadsheet with two cells (C2/C3) having an array formula:

```
{=NaNTest()}
```

My simplified CustomFunction is as follows:

```
public class NaNTest : CustomFunctions.Function
{
    public NaNTest() : this( "NaNTest" ) { }
    public NaNTest( string name ) : base( name, CustomFunctions.Volatility.Invariant, CustomFunctions.ValueType.Variant ) { }

    public override void Evaluate( CustomFunctions.IArguments a, CustomFunctions.IValue r )
    {
        var result = new double[ 1, 2 ];
        result[ 0, 0 ] = double.NaN;
        result[ 0, 1 ] = 0d;
        r.SetArray( result );
    }
}
```

This sets both C2 and C3 to *#NUM!* when I'd expect *only* C2 to be.  Is there a way to make it correctly* assign C3 to 0?

Thanks in advance.

* I say *correctly* because we have to implement an Excel add-in that our clients use to author spreadsheets and it provides same 'functionality' that we provide on 'our servers' when we open/process the spreadsheet in our 'SpreadsheetGear calculations' (i.e. the NaNTest() function above).  The libraries we use to create the add-in only assign C2 to #NUM! and having the two implementations (client side add-in vs server side SpreadsheetGear) behaving differently makes maintenance/debugging difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design.  Note the comment in the documentation for the IValue.[SetArray](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.CustomFunctions.IValue~SetArray(Double[,]).html)(...) method:

> If any of the numbers in the array are not valid numbers, the result
>   of the custom function will be ValueError.Num.

Since NaN isn't a valid number the entire array will resolve to #NUM! instead.  Actually, if you try to set a cell value on its out (outside of a custom function), such as...

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = double.NaN;
```

...you should find that cell evaluates to #NUM! as well.  If such cases can occur in your custom function, you'll likely just need to write a check for this condition and respond in whatever manner is required by your application.

Comment: Thanks.  We'll take precautions in our custom functions to try and protect from that and in addition make our 'other component' behave the same way. (FYI I tried Googling your site to see if I could find anything in SetArray but nothing came up...)